# Error Message: "Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, entity-framework

I'm working a report for an asp.net page and I'm trying to assign the results of this linq statement to an existing dataset but I'm receiving the "Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context." Error message. Here's my code:

```
   var contextTable = new dbpersonnelEntities();                
   var contextHistory = new WriterInResidenceEntities();

   var rslt = (from c in contextTable.TableofOrganizationRpts
            where !(from o in contextHistory.emp_history
            select o.employeeID).Contains((int)c.employeeid_fk)
                       select c).ToList();

   ReportDataSource r = new ReportDataSource("tableOfOrgDS", rslt);
```

Comment: Are `dbpersonnelEntities` and `WriterInResidenceEntities` two different types, derived from `ObjectContext` (or `DbContext`)?

Comment: @Dennis Yes they are two different types derived from two distinct entity models. I'm trying to simply list all the employees from the TableofOrganizationRpts table that don't exist in the emp_history table. If I try using a single objectcontext in the code it would work but it's when I try doing this join that I get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mix entity types from different contexts in single LINQ query. Either put them into single context, or try to execute this:

```
var employeeIds = (from o in contextHistory.emp_history select o.employeeID).ToList();
```

and then pass this list into the second query:

```
var rslt = (from c in contextTable.TableofOrganizationRpts
            where !employeeIds.Contains((int)c.employeeid_fk)
            select c).ToList();
```

This should generate `IN` condition in resulting SQL query. Note, that this might work slow.

Comment: This worked flawlessly! It's a rather short list so there's barely any latency. Thank you very much!! I'm new to entity framework and I'll know now how to properly work with more than one entity type.